# Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which re

Tags: java, linux, amazon-aws

Ao tentar executar um relatorio que contem uma imagem fixa em um servidor linux da Amazon. Aparece a exceçãoa abaixo. Alguem ja passou por isso ?

```
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but
this program performed an operation which requires it. at 
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204) at 
java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536) at java.awt.Frame.<init>
(Frame.java:420) at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) at 
javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.<init>(JasperViewer.java:267) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:655) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:587) at 
net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.viewReport(JasperViewer.java:535) at 
util.report.ExecutorComprovante.execute(ExecutorComprovante.java:49) ... 51 
more
```

Comment: Se eu setar o Display com esse comando: export DISPLAY=:0.0 A exceção do Display muda e mostra apenas                                                                                                                         Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
 at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
 at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
 at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
 at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
 at net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer.<init>(JasperViewer.java:267)
 at

Comment: Edite a pergunta no botão `Editar`abaixo das `tags` e complemente.

Comment: Só pra confirmar, que distro você está utilizando? Ubuntu? Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Muitas vezes este tipo de erro ocorre quando algum código rodando fora de um ambiente gráfico, como no seu caso, em um servidor, tenta executar algo que usa uma biblioteca de gráficos.

Uma boa tentativa é instalar um Java *headless*. Em Ubuntu você faria algo como:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk-7-jre-headless
```

Answer (score 1):

O Jasper Reports usa algumas funcionalidades do *awt* para manipulação de imagens, mas ele não necessita de um ambiente gráfico "real" para gerar um relatório pois nada é realmente enviado para o *display*. Para gerar relatórios em servidores sem nenhum ambiente gráfico instalado um *workaround* conhecido é rodar a JVM em modo *headless*, isso é, inicializar o processo da sua aplicação (ou container, servidor de aplicação, etc) com:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

**Fonte** [Jaspersoft Community - Setting JVM Options for Application Servers](http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/jasperreports-server-install-guide/v561/setting-jvm-options-application-servers)